# MY SQL Query for salary sheet

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables in MYSQL From 2 different database running in same server

[image]

and my expected Output is

[image]

MY attempt of query is

```
SELECT `biometric`.`Empid`,
,`name`,`location`,`basic`,`hra`,`conveyance`,`total salary`,sum(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(LEAST(`endDate`,'$monthEnd' ),GREATEST(`startdate`,'$monthStart'))+1) as leaves FROM `biometric`.`biometric`,`biometric`.`employee` JOIN `lms`.`leaves` WHERE `biometric`.`empid`= `employee`.`empid` AND `employee`.`empid` = `leaves`.`id` AND  
`startdate`<='$monthEnd' AND `endDate`>= '$monthStart' AND `leaves`.`status` = '3'
GROUP BY `Empid`
```

and here status =3 is approved leave and 1 is non approved leave.
and my out put coming is

[image]
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: you have `leaves`.`status` = '3' in your where clause hence only employees who has approved leaves will come in your output rest will not come... (either remove this condition Or do a LEFT join to leaves table )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query, even I did not test it so if you get any error then you can create an sqlfiddle so that I can correct it.

Basic concept is that you need to use left join for lms.leaves table as you need all employee details even they did not took leave under status 3.

```
SELECT bmt.`Empid`,`name`,`location`,`basic`,`hra`,`conveyance`,`total salary`,
IFNULL(SUM(DISTINCT DATEDIFF(LEAST(`endDate`,'$monthEnd' ),GREATEST(`startdate`,'$monthStart'))+1),0) AS LEAVES 
FROM BM.`biometric` AS bmt
JOIN BM.`employee` AS emp ON bmt.`empid`= emp.`empid`
LEFT JOIN `lms`.`leaves` AS lvs ON emp.`empid` = lvs.`id` AND lvs.`status` = '3' AND `startdate`<='$monthEnd' AND `endDate`>= '$monthStart' 
GROUP BY bmt.`Empid`;
```

Comment: Use updated query sorry I did not check that you are using date from leaves table.....